# How do I robocopy files from iPhone DCIM folder to my computer?

Tags: windows, iphone

I want to copy photos from my iPhone to my computer, and I want to retain the creation dates.  Without installing third party programs.  Is this possible?

I would think it should be possible with robocopy, but Windows Command Line prompt isn't able to navigate to my iPhone, even when Windows Explorer can.

Comment: Mobile devices do not connect as normal storage, even if they may be presented as such. Unless you can find and set up a filesystem driver for mobile devices that does mount them as actual storage, you won't be able to use Robocopy or other methods to interact with the files.

Comment: Apparently iExplorer may offer the required ability to mount iPhones as accessible drives: https://macroplant.com/iexplorer/tutorials/how-to-auto-mount-a-directory-on-iphone-ipad-ipod